# dateparser search_dates returns impossible year

Tags: python, dateparser

I'm using dateparser's "search_dates" to parse text for dates and got a strange date in my result.

```
dateparser.__version__
'1.1.8'


settings= {
 'RELATIVE_BASE': datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 31, 0, 0),
 'PREFER_DAY_OF_MONTH': 'first',
 'PREFER_DATES_FROM': 'future',
 'REQUIRE_PARTS': ['year', 'month'],
 'DATE_ORDER': 'YMD'
}
s = 'Closing Yield, 2010 Year Treasury notes On Dec 31, 2023'
search_dates(s, settings=settings)
```

Result:

```
Out[27]: 
[('2010 Year', datetime.datetime(4033, 7, 31, 0, 0)),
 ('On Dec 31, 2023', datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 31, 0, 0))]
```

The first item in the list yields an impossible result (year = 4033).

Any ideas here?

Comment: I would guess that your `'PREFER_DATES_FROM': 'future'` is causing the parser to assume that "2010 Year" must be interpreted as "2010 years from now" which when combined with your RELATIVE_BASE gets you `datetime(4033, 7, 31, 0, 0)`

Comment: Thank you.  That does now make sense.   I would have thought the REQUIRE_PARTS setting of [year, month] would have blocked the parse of ‘2010 Year’ anyway.

Answer (score 0):

with help from @Malcolm and contributor via Github:

> This is because year is interpreted the same as years, and “2010
> years” is interpreted as “2010 years later“.
>
> Maybe we could make it so that if it is year, singular, it only works
> like that for “1 year”, and otherwise it gets translated to “year
> 2010” for example. But it may not be trivial to address.